# How to get the number of lines from a jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, word-wrap

Is there a way of "extracting" the number of lines from a filled with text jtextpane?
If there is, does it work if some of the lines are due to text wrapping?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Utilities.getRowStart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html#getRowStart%28javax.swing.text.JTextComponent,%20int%29) to determine the 'start' of the line for a `JTextPane` giving you a resulting `lineCount`. This will also work when the lines are wrapped.

```
int totalCharacters = textPane.getText().length(); 
int lineCount = (totalCharacters == 0) ? 1 : 0;

try {
   int offset = totalCharacters; 
   while (offset > 0) {
      offset = Utilities.getRowStart(textPane, offset) - 1;
      lineCount++;
   }
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just a note: "This will also work when the lines are wrapped." means that if a line gets wrapped automatically, the resulting number will be increased by the amount of wraps. So, when you eg. want to display line numbers, you have to check if a line really is a line or just displayed as a line because of automatic wrapping.

Answer (score 5):

If you define a "line" as how many `\n` characters are there in a JTextPane text, then you could use:

```
JTextPane p = yourJTextPane;
System.out.println(p.getText().split("\n").length);
```

Comment: Thanks, though I already tried that. The problem is that when the jtextPane wraps a line, it seems that it doesn't put a "\n"? I can't really undestand why.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If that's what you need, you can't use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To jump to line that was selected, I used this code:

```
int rowSel = Integer.parseInt(tfGoLine.getText());

        int rowGo = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int totalCharacters = rowSel <= 1 ? 0 : text.getText().length();

        try {
            int last = -1;
            for (int count = 0; count < totalCharacters; count++) {
                int offset = Utilities.getRowStart(text, count);

                if (last != offset) {
                    last = offset;
                    lineCount++;
                    rowGo = offset;

                    if (lineCount == rowSel) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }

        text.getCaret().setDot(rowGo);
        text.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowCount =txtPane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElementCount();
```